# Prevent Spring boot application from starting up if JDBC connection can not be established

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Currently,default behaviour the Spring boot server is that it starts (throws/logs error but still starts) even when it cannot establish JDBC connection to backend due to incorrect host/port or database name or authentication failures. I wanted the application to fail instead.(why to simply launch the server when it could n't connect to database or serve any requests) Any idea how to achieve the same.Also i use spring data jpa to interact the database.

Comment: Since you tagged `rest`, you're likely talking about a web server application, which usually runs 24/7. The database may be *temporarily* unavailable during startup of the web application, or at any time while it is running, so shutting down the application just because the database is not *currently* available is a bad idea. If you just installed or reconfigured the webapp, it's up to you to verify that every is ok, including the connection. The Spring webapp shouldn't fail because of it. **Recommendation: Don't do this.**

Comment: Hi @Andreas thanks for your comment. I wanted to fail only during web server start up when for example incorrect jdbc connection details are provided in properties file and not at later point of time when database is temporarily down. In such a case there is no point of starting up the server. You can reproduce this error by providing incorrect/non-existent db in jdbc url

Comment: But if there is a power failure or you're simply rebooting all servers for some reason, the webapp server will likely start the webapp *before* the database server has completed starting the database, so *during startup*, the database will be unavailable, and your webapp will fail to start, if you do this. If the webapp was allowed to start normally, it would be available for normal use soon after, when the database server is ready. If you do implement this ill-conceived logic, the webapp may fail to restart after a reboot, for no good reason. It's a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @Andreas: what if i give incorrect jdbc url in properties file and try to start spring boot web server? What is the point of starting webapp ?I want to web app to fail in such case. I would like to start only if can successfully establish connection with db. I'm not talking about case of shutting down the application just because the database is not currently available or at later point of time.

Comment: If database server is not responding, is it because it's rebooting (temporary issue), or because you configured connection wrong (permanent issue)? How are you going to know the difference? You can't. But bad configuration is a one-time event, that you immediate check and fix. Server rebooting is a recurring issue, and you don't want to have to manually restart application if that happens. As I already said, it would be a maintenance nightmare. Letting the webapp run with bad config is temporary maintenance until you fix it.